# Spivak, Ch. 22, "Infinite Sequences", Step in Problem 26c: Given $e^{-1}\leq b\leq e$ and $a=b^{1/b}$, how to obtain $e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Given $$e^{-1}\leq b\leq e\tag{1}$$

and

$$a=b^{1/b}\tag{2}$$

How do we derive the result that

$$e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}\tag{3}$$

**For context about how this question arose**

The following is a problem from Ch. 22 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 26. This problem investigates for which $a>0$ the symbol
>
> $$a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}$$
>
> makes sense. In other words, if we define a sequence $\{b_n\}$ by
>
> $$b_1=a$$
>
> $$b_n+1=a^{b_n}$$
>
> when does
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n=b$$
>
> exist?
>
> (a) If $b$ exists, then $a$ can be written in the form $y^{1/y}$ for
> some $y$. Describe the graph of $g(y)=y^{1/y}$ and conclude that
> $0<a\leq e^{1/e}$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $1\leq a \leq e^{1/e}$. Show that $\{b_n\}$ is
> increasing and also that $b_n\leq e$. This proves that $b$ exists (and
> also that $b\leq e$)
>
> The analysis for $a<1$ is more difficult.
>
> (c) Using Problem 25, show that if $b$ exists, then $e^{-1}\leq b\leq e$. Then show that $e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}$.

My question is about a single step in item $(c)$ that seems to involve essentially an understanding of inequalities.

**Let me go through the items to reach the point where the question arises.** If you want to see the question directly, just skip to the last part.

Note that $\{b_n\}$ is the sequence

$$a, f(a), f(f(a)), f(f(f(a))), ...$$

The general task is to figure out for which $a$ this sequence converges.

If it does exist then (as proved in a previous problem) the limit is a fixed point of $f$, ie it is some value $b$ such that

$$f(b)=b=a^b$$

and thus we can write

$$a=b^{1/b}$$

If we plot the function $g(x)=x^{1/x}$ we arrive at

[image]

What this graph tells us is that $a$ can't be just any value. Since $x^{1/x}$ reaches a max value of $e^{1/e}$ at $x=e$, then $a$ can only be between $0$ and $e^{1/e}$.

**Part b**

Assume that $1\leq a\leq e^{1/e}$.

We can show that for such values of $a$, $\{b_n\}$ is increasing and bounded above.

$$b_1=a\geq 1$$

$$b_2=a^a\geq b_1\geq 1$$

If we assume $b_n\geq b_{n-1}$, then $b_{n+1}=a^{b_n}>a^{b_{n-1}}=b_n$.

By induction, we can infer that $\{b_n\}$ is increasing.

Using another induction argument we can show that $b_n<e$. Thus, since $\{b_n\}$ is bounded above and increasing, it converges.

**Part c**

Here is what what proved in Problem 25

> If $\{b_n\}$ is a sequence defined by $b_1=a$ and $b_{n+1}=f(b_n)$,
> then if $b=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists and $f'$ is continuous
> at $b$, then $|f'(b)|\leq 1$ (provided we don't already have $b_n=b$
> for some $n$).

We can apply this directly to the current problem. The only thing to check is the condition on $f'$.

$$f'(x)=a^x\log{(a)}$$

which is continuous.

Therefore, if we assume that $b=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists, then by the result above we infer that $|f'(b)|\leq 1$ which means

$$|f'(b)|=|a^b\log{(a)}|=|b\log{(a)}|=|\log{(a^b)}|=|log{(b)}|\leq 1$$

$$-1\leq\log{(b)}\leq 1$$

$$e^{-1}\leq b\leq e\tag{1}$$

**Now, for the question**

How do we derive the result that

$$e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}\tag{3}$$

?

The solution manuals says

Since $$a=b^{1/b}\tag{2}$$ we have

$$(e^{-1})^{1/e^{-1}}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}\tag{4}$$

or

$$e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}\tag{3}$$

How do we get from $(1)$ to $(3)$ using $(2)$?

Comment: As other responses have indicated, in general, when you are attempting to examine the behavior of the function $f(x)$, for $a \leq x \leq b,$ the **first try**, which may not lead to a conclusive result, should be to examine the behavior of $f'(x)$ for $-a \leq x \leq b.$  That is, you examine the behavior of $f(x)$, by examining the behavior of its derivative.

Answer (score 1):

$b \mapsto b^{1/b}$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,e]$. So $b \leq e$ implies $b^{1/b} \leq e^{1/e}$. Similarly, $b \geq e^{-1}$ implies $b^{1/b} \geq (e^{-1})^{1/e^{-1}}$.  Finally, $(e^{-1})^{1/e^{-1}}$ is same as $e^{-e}$.

[$\frac d  {db} b^{1/b}=b^{1/b} \frac {1-\log   b}  {b^{2} } \geq 0$ if $\log b \leq 1$ or $b \leq e$].

Answer (score 0):

Define the function:
$$f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
for $x > 0$. Then:
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} x^{\frac{1}{x}} = \frac{d}{dx} \exp \left(\frac{1}{x} \log(x) \right) = x^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(-\frac{\log(x)}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^2} \right)$$
This is non-negative on $(0,e]$. As a consequence, $f$ is increasing. In particular:
$$f(e^{-1}) \leq f(b) \leq f(e)$$
$$e^{-e} \leq a \leq e^{\frac{1}{e}}$$
and we are done.