# Spivak, Ch. 22, "Infinite Sequences", Problem 26f: Understanding the solution manual solution

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems

I have a question about item (f) in a very long problem in Spivak's *Calculus*.

Here is the problem statement

> 26. This problem investigates for which $a>0$ the symbol
>
> $$a^{a^{a^{a^{...}}}}$$
>
> makes sense. In other words, if we define a sequence $\{b_n\}$ by
>
> $$b_1=a$$
>
> $$b_{n+1}=a^{b_n}$$
>
> when does
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n=b$$
>
> exist?
>
> (a) If $b$ exists, then $a$ can be written in the form $y^{1/y}$ for
> some $y$. Describe the graph of $g(y)=y^{1/y}$ and conclude that
> $0<a\leq e^{1/e}$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $1\leq a \leq e^{1/e}$. Show that $\{b_n\}$ is
> increasing and also that $b_n\leq e$. This proves that $b$ exists (and
> also that $b\leq e$)
>
> The analysis for $a<1$ is more difficult.
>
> (c) Using Problem 25, show that if $b$ exists, then $e^{-1}\leq b\leq e$. Then show that $e^{-e}\leq a \leq e^{1/e}$.
>
> From now on we will suppose that $e^{-e}\leq a \leq 1$.
>
> (d) Show that the function
>
> $$f(x)=\frac{a^x}{\log{x}}$$
>
> is decreasing on the interval $(0,1)$.
>
> (e) Let $b$ be the unique number such that $a^b=b$. Show that $$a<b<1\tag{1}$$
> Using part $(e)$ [sic], show that if $0<x<b$, then $$x<a^{a^{x}}<b\tag{2}$$
> Conclude that $$l=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{2n+1}\tag{3}$$ exists and that
> $$a^{a^l}=l\tag{4}$$
>
> (f) Using part $(e)$ again [sic], show that $l=b$.

[I've asked about item (c) before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4560217/spivak-ch-22-infinite-sequences-step-in-problem-26c-given-e-1-leq-b-l?noredirect=1#comment9593098_4560217), and there I show the solution up to item (c).

Let me continue almost where I left off in that other question, skipping item (d) and starting from item (e) to reach my question in (f).

**Item e**

Note the graph of $f(x)=x^{1/x}$ below. Since $e^{-e}\leq a<1$ then we are on a portion of the graph where it is increasing and thus one-one.

[image]

Note that on this interval, $x^{1/x}$ lies below $x$ because

$$0<x<1\implies \frac{1}{x}>1\implies \frac{1}{x}\log{x}<\log{x}\implies x^{1/x}<x$$

Thus, since $a$ is in this interval, we have

$$a=b^{1/b}<b<1\tag{1}$$

Now, assume that $0<x<b$.

Then $a^x>a^b$ since

$$f(x)=a^x, f'(x)=a^x\log{a}\leq 0\text{ since } 0\leq e^{-e}<a<1$$

Then,

$$a^{a^x}<a^b=b\tag{5}$$

by the same argument. That is, $a^x$ is decreasing for $e^{-e}\leq a<1$. Hence, given $a^x>a^b$ we have $a^{a^x}<a^b=b$.

In part (d) we showed that $\frac{a^x}{\log{x}}$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$. Thus, since $x<b$, then $\frac{a^x}{\log{x}}>\frac{a^b}{\log{b}}$ and

$$a^x\log{b}>a^b\log{x}$$

$$a^x\log{(a^b)}>b\log{x}$$

$$a^xb\log{a}>b\log{x}$$

$$a^x\log{a}>\log{x}$$

$$\log{a^{a^x}}>\log{x}$$

$$a^{a^x}>x\tag{6}$$

(5) and (6) give us (2)

$$x<a^{a^x}<b\tag{2}$$

In particular, we have

$$0<a=b_1<b\implies a<a^{a^a}=b_3<b\implies a^{a^a}<a^{a^{a^a}}=b_5<b$$

Thus, the subsequence $\{b_{2n+1}\}$ is increasing and bounded, hence convergent. That is, for some $l$ we have

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_{2n+1}=l\tag{3}$$

Now, $\{b_{2n+1}\}$ is the sequence $a,f(a),f(f(a)),...$ with $f(x)=a^{a^x}$.

By a previous result, since this sequence converges, it must converge to a fixed point of $f$.

Thus, $$f(l)=a^{a^l}=l\tag{4}$$

**Now for the question.**

**Item f**

We want to prove that $l=b$. The solution manual simply says

> Since $a^b=b$ we have $a^{a^b}=a^b=b$. Since we also have $a^{a^l}=l$
> we must have $l=b$ by part $(e)$.

What exactly is happening in this solution?